# How to analysis the correlation of one value corresponding to multiple values

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation

For example, there is a school teacher's answering score corresponding to multiple students' answering scores (which like 1 for unlikely, and 5 for very likely). For analyzing the correlation of this kind of data, what statistics method could I use?